# Obter parametro da url em requisção GET usando REST

Tags: php, rest

Olá pessoal possuo uma dúvida. Quando eu faço a requisição:

> GET /sacar/30

Como o valor "30" não esta vinculado a uma chave, então não da para usar o `$_GET['chave']`.

A maneira que achei foi fazer isso:

```
$valor = end(explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Não é algo muito bonito, mas funciona.

Será que há uma forma melhor de fazer isso sem usar um Framework? Em CakePHP faço isso de boa, porém sem ele complicou o meio de campo.

Answer (score 1):

O PHP não trabalha nativamente com esse formato de URL e com tantos *packages* por ai que fazem a função de *routing*, não vejo muito propósito em refazer a roda.

O que você pode fazer é utilizar algum componente que faça o *routing* da sua aplicação. Que tal usar um microframework já com suporte a *routing*, como o Silex ou Lumen?

Exemplo simples com [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/):

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
}); 

$app->run();
```

Exemplo com [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation) (arquivo `app/Http/routes.php`)

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

$app->post('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Comment: Bacana cara, não sei se vale a pena para o momento eu usar, mais curti a ideia e quando precisar de algo mais robusto já sei que existe. A aplicação que estou fazendo é simples e somente tem requisição GET, com uma única URL, é uma provinha pratica para um emprego. Valeu pelas dicas.